# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Is given when attempting to migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, migration

I am attempting to migrate 3 models using:

```
php artisan migrate
```

But I am given the error mentioned in the title
This is the rest of the error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your 
MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'created_at) null, `updated_at`
timestamp(created_at) null, `created_at` times...' at line 1
```

This is my code:

```
Schema::create('v_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->id('userid');
            $table->string('full_Name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('phone_No');
            $table->string('role');
            $table->timestamps('created_at');
            $table->timestamps('updated_at');
```

```
Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id('v_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('userid')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('v_plate_no');
            $table->string('v_brand');
            $table->string('v_model');
            $table->string('v_color');
            $table->timestamps('created_at');
            $table->timestamps('updated_at');
```

```
Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->id('reportid');
            $table->foreign('vehicleid')->references('v_id')->on('vehicles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps('created_at');
            $table->timestamps('updated_at');
```

I am new to coding in general and would very much appreciate some feedback, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71085906/edit) and post the full error message? Not everyone knows what MySQL error 1064 is without Googling it, and showing the full error can help us help you better.

Comment: 1. You should have only one timestamps() without any column name. 2. Make sure the files listed in correct order on the folder. For example, if reports is above the vehicles you will get error, because to create foreign key, reports needs vehicles. 3. I strongly suggest you follow naming conventions, it will help massivly. Laravel have to many handy stuff that relies some naming standars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing that jumps out to me in your migrations is how you're doing your timestamp columns.

The `timestamps` method does not take a column name, see here:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#column-method-timestamps

The only argument for this method is precision, should you want to customize that. Right now you're basically specifying a precision of `created_at` which I can imagine would cause a query failure.

You just need to do this...

```
$table->timestamps();
```

... and Laravel will create both the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns for you.

If you need to explicitly create your own timestamp column, make sure you use the `timestamp()` method (no 's' at the end):

https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#column-method-timestamp

Comment: Thank you friend! Worked well now I just need to fix my foreign key constraint haha